# State space of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

so I started reading a bit on stochastic processes and I have encountered definitions that consider the space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{T}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real line. $\mathbb{T}$ is an indexing set, for example the natural numbers or $[0,1]$. For example, let us define the probability measure of a stochastic process: Let $X = (\xi_t)_{t\in \mathbb{T}}$ be a random process. The probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ on $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{T},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{T}))$ is defined by
$$ \mathbb{P}_X(B) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\in B\}),\quad B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{T}),$$
is called a probability distribution of $X$.

Here $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{T})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of that suggested space. The definition of the probability distribution is not what is confusing me, but the space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$. I can't seem to understand completely what it means.

My attempt: I know that a stochastic process depends on both $\omega$ and $t$, so if we fix $\omega$ we end up with a realization $(\xi_t(\omega))_{t\in \mathbb{T}}$ which i  usually view as a function. Hence, my intuition is that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ is just telling me that for each fixed $\omega$ you are getting a sequence mapped to $\mathbb{R}$ from each $t\in \mathbb{T}$. i.e. fix a an $\omega$, and then we have $ \mathbb{T} \ni t\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. So the indexing set is just there to tell us about the mapping. However, i am confused if this is the correct way of viewing it, since what would the Borel sigma-algebra be in this case and why put it as a power of $\mathbb{R}$ instead of just saying, we have an indexing set that maps to the reals. So i think my intuition could be off, but that's why i am here, maybe someone could help me in understanding this space and the sigma algebra of it. Thanks :)!!

Y